# "ssh localhost " command is showing 20 bad configuration options

Tags: ssh, connection, localhost, hadoop

```
hduser1@archit-HP-Notebook:~$ ssh localhost
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 11: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 12: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 13: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 14: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 16: Bad configuration option: useprivilegeseparation
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 19: Bad configuration option: keyregenerationinterval
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 20: Bad configuration option: serverkeybits
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 23: Bad configuration option: syslogfacility
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 27: Bad configuration option: logingracetime
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 28: Bad configuration option: permitrootlogin
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 29: Bad configuration option: strictmodes
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 36: Bad configuration option: ignorerhosts
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 45: Bad configuration option: permitemptypasswords
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 64: Bad configuration option: x11forwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 65: Bad configuration option: x11displayoffset
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 66: Bad configuration option: printmotd
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 67: Bad configuration option: printlastlog
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 75: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 77: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 88: Bad configuration option: usepam
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 20 bad configuration options
```

Comment: can anybody help me for this

Comment: What did you do to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`? Post the file contents in the question.

Comment: Have you check syntax with `sshd -T` command ?

Answer (score 8):

Open the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and remove all the listed options. They are supposed to be part of the `sshd_config` (the server configuration), not the client one.